# How to Compress Css/js code in wordpress and increase loading speed?

Tags: css, html

Currently, I'm working my blog with good server still working and loading speed very slow https://www.startupopinions.com/. I have installed one plugin is total cache and compress the code but still working very slow... let me know guys is theme issues or main development part issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you determined what part of your page/site is loading slowly? Images, plugins, theme files, whatever?

Use the Developer Tools in your browser (usually F12) and look at the Network tab to see the load time of your various page elements. Once you identify the slow parts, then you can ask the googles on the best way to speed things up.

For instance, if your images are slow to load, then optimizing the images (compressing them) will help. You can minimize code/css, but (in most cases, IMHO) that won't help.

What will help is identifying the slow parts of your site.